# SimpleDraweeView cannot be cast to custom View that extends ImageView

Tags: java, android

I need to save a number inside an `ImageView` object so I can access it later in my code. That's why I created a custom class that extends `ImageView`:

```
public class SliderView extends ImageView {

    private int position;

    public SliderView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SliderView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    public SliderView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public void setViewPosition(int pos){
        this.position = pos;
    }

    public int getPosition(){
        return position;
    }
}
```

This is my SimpleDraweeView object in .xml :

```
<com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
    android:id="@+id/bottomslider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     />
```

And what I am trying to achieve is this:

```
final SliderView mediaImage = (SliderView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bottomslider);
```

When I try to run the above code, I get this error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView cannot be cast to
>   android.custom.SliderView

If I use `ImageView` instead of `SliderView` everything works fine, but I don't have the functionality that I need. Is there any workaround?

Comment: i guess you want to use this `SimpleDraweeView mediaImage = (SimpleDraweeView)` instead of this `SliderView mediaImage = (SliderView)`;  or the other way around in xml

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SliderView extends ImageView {

private int position;

public SliderView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public SliderView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
}
public SliderView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public SliderView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}

public void setViewPosition(int pos){
    this.position = pos;
}

public int getPosition(){
    return position;
}
```

}

Try this, and let me know if this works